# Image normalization and reverse normalization: colors lost on image generation (GAN)

Tags: normalization, gan, image-preprocessing

I'm working on a Gan.
Based on different papers, I use a Tanh activation function on the last layer of the generator. Which produces [-1,1] outputs.

To make this coherent, I use image normalization with cv2:

```
cv2.normalize(image, image, alpha=-1, beta=1, norm_type=cv2.NORM_MINMAX, dtype=cv2.CV_32F)
```

Example:

origin image: [image]

normalized image: [image]

(first image is 32,32, second is probably 128,128 it is for the sake of demonstration)

We can clearly see the colours are not the same.
After training the models for 10 hours. I can generate all this images, which are interesting:
[image]

Here's how I generate and plot my images:

```
latent_points = generate_latent_points(100, 20)
generated = generator_model.predict(latent_points)

plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
for i in range(generated.shape[0]):
    plt.subplot(4, 5, i+1)
    image = generated[i, :, :, :]
    image = np.reshape((image), [32, 32, 3])
    plt.imshow(image, vmin=-1, vmax=1)
    plt.axis('off')
plt.tight_layout()
```

My question: is this kind of result normal? is it the way I normalize images that is wrong, or should I apply some transformation after the generation?

Comment: If you use normalized images to train your GAN on the GAN will learn to produce images in that same range. If you want see the result in the original value range you will have to apply the inverse transform to the output of the model.

Comment: It's the process of "inverse transform" that I don't understand in this case. The transformartion is done on each input image, each with its max/min. How can that be reproduced on the output image generated by the Gan?

Comment: You generally perform the transformations based on the attributes of the whole dataset instead of a specific sample. So if the value range of the whole dataset is 0-255 but a single image has values in the range 0-120 you transform the image based on the 0-255 range. When the GAN creates new images you can then use the 0-255 to perform the inverse transformation.